# How to limit transform.Rotate(float,0,0)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know that there are some answers in Google, but I cannot limit the rotation with the code:

```
pitch = cameraDirectionSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

cameraPivot.transform.Rotate(-pitch, 0, 0, Space.Self);
```

I wish to have limits from **0** to **90** on the **X** axis.

Thank you!

Comment: So add some code to clamp the `pitch` value?

Comment: It doesn't work in this way. It is the Rotate function. Clamping gives you nothing.

Comment: Of course it works, you just need to figure out the logic yourself. (Hint: try adding `pitch` to `transform.localEulerAngles.x` and see what you get)

Comment: I know I can use localEulerAngles, but I need the limits for the Rotate function. Please read the question. Rotate adds rotation, not set.

Answer (score 0):

Use Quaternion instead.

```
public Vector3 rotation;
private GameObject go;

private void Start()
{
    go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
}

void Update()
{
    go.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(Mathf.Clamp(rotation.x, 0, 90), 
    rotation.y, rotation.z);
}
```

---

```
public class CameraClamp : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Vector2 clamp; // x = min, y = max
    private float pitch;

    private void Update()
    {
        pitch += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        //pitch -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed * Time.deltaTime; // Invert
        pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, clamp.x, clamp.y);
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(pitch, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried various ways of your solution. None works. `cameraPivot.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Mathf.Clamp(pitch, 0, 90), 0, 0);`

Comment: @Orson I show you how it works, but I added what you need.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the rotation is set instead of adding. Is there a way to make some limits for the Rotate function? Rotate works perfectly, but I need to limit the Pitch rotation. How?

Comment: @Orson what are you trying to do? why you need Rotate()

Comment: It is hard to explain in short. I need Rotate() because I have implemented many controls for my camera and the camera shouldn't move unexpectedly if we start using the Yaw or Pitch. Rotate() adds the rotation to the existing one not causing any unwanted "jumps". Other solutions cause those "jumps". I have tried all what I know and only Rotate() works perfectly.

Comment: @Orson what do you mean it's "Unexpectedly" and "Jumps"?
The problem using Rotate() it's difficult to get control because is always updating, I always avoid it and personally I prefer quaternions

Comment: Rotate() adds rotation to the existing one, so the camera is not suddenly reset with other values. All works smoothly. Your solution (and other ones) resets the camera (not add), providing its transform with other values, so you understand that the camera's rotation is changed quickly, for example, from up to down 10 degrees. The owner of our project requires me to make the camera work smoothly.

Comment: @Orson In other words, you want "Smoothness" or "Damping", if so, try using Vector3.Lerp or Vector3.SmoothDamp... Using the code I posted above